# Angular 10 won't recognize absolute path aliases

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to get absolute pathing and aliases to work in my app. I keep getting errors.

tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src", //also tried without the ./
    "paths": {
      "@component/*": ["app/components/*"],
...
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from '@component/app.component';
...
```

^ the second line works when it's: `from 'src/app/components/app.component`

Folder structure:

```
- project
  - client
      tsconfig.json
    - src
      - app
        - components
            app.component.ts
```

error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:7:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@component/app.component' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import { AppComponent } from '@component/app.component';
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

fwiw, VScode is also telling me the imports are invalid, but no clues as to what's wrong.

Edit: this is what's set in angluar.json:

```
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
```

Comment: Did you configure this tsconfig in angular.json?

Comment: no; I haven't seen any links that suggest that. This is what's set in angular.json: ...      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",...

Comment: for default import AppComponent is: import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

Comment: @tomasz Not helpful. Yes, that's the default. I moved it. It works fine. Nothing works if i try to use path aliases.

Comment: I did it exaclty like you, and for me it's working... Have you edited in tsconfig.base.json or in the tsconfig.json? For me the baseUrl: "./src" was actually the key to make it work.